# How to implement Google Search bar in custom app?

Tags: java, android, search

How can I implement Google Search bar in custom application?

I found some sources, but that's very difficult to implement (too much variables and values). I want implement search bar, when I can search via text and voice like original search bar in Google Now Launcher.

Link to image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHHOL.jpg